# Can I cite something while specifying exactly what text will appear at that place?

Tags: bibliographies, biblatex, citing, natbib, tufte

First up, I'm using `natbib`.

I'm trying implement a citation style (Thankfully only a few citations, so I'm happy to work things by hand) that is essentially of the following form:

- At the point of citation one has a superscript number, referring to a footnote (well, `\sidenote`, actually)
- The footnote<sup>1</sup> contains version 1 of the citation, for example

> <sup>1</sup>Fname LName, *Title* (Publisher info) pageno.

- The citation also appears in the bibliography, in version 2:

> LName, FName *Title* Publisher Info

I was thinking of using a command

```
\newcommand{\mycite}[2]{%
  \sidenote{\modifiedcite{#1}\citetext{#2}}%
}
```

where `\modifiedcite` generated an entry in the bibliography from a `.bib` file, but placed nothing in the text at that point.

Ideally, one would actually generate the footnote from the information contained in the `.bib` file together with a page number, but this is far beyond me.

Edit: I'm not married to `natbib`, but I had a look at the `biblatex` so-called manual, and my goodness, I think I'd have to learn a new language to use it.

Here are some clarifying points:

This is for my wife's honours project (in music). LaTeX is completely alien to her, so I'm just taking her Wrod document and typesetting it properly. I don't want to learn a whole new package for a <15 page article. I'm not going to use this sort of system ever again.

The thesis uses something the university's citation guidelines call MLA, but having had a look at the online MLA citation style guidelines (including TeX-based solutions), I find it hard to recognise as such. For instance, it asks for basically a complete bibliographic record for a source for the first time it is cited (in an endnote, but I'm using a wide-margin format and using `\sidenote`, no matter the complaints), with a page number reference. After that, each citation of the same work gets an 'Author-surname, page-no.' end/sidenote. Then there is a bibliography, which is more than just the works cited, and each entry is in a subtly different style to before (as outlined above).

To make things easier, I'll remove all prescriptions, and ask: what is the best way to do this, keeping in mind the payoff between reproducibility/good practice/time and effort.

Comment: I'm not really an expert on bibliographies in LaTeX, but have you seen `biblatex`?

Comment: I didn't get the question. What do you mean exactly when you say you're "trying implement a citation style" but you "work things by hand"? Are you actually writing your own `.bst` file or are you just modifying your `.tex` document? If the latter case is true, then I'm not quite sure whether your goal can be achieved. I think you do need an own `.bst` style that reads the information from the `.bib` database, formats them, and provides your command `\modifiedcite`.

Comment: Another approach might be to include and format your `\bibitem`s manually into your `.tex` document, without using the `.bib` file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[A recent question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25891/4483) mentioned a [revision of tufte-latex](https://tufte-latex.googlecode.com/svn-history/r173/trunk/tufte-common.def) that allows one to use biblatex instead of natbib.

It sounds like biblatex's built-in style `verbose` meets most of your requirements, but every citation after the first are printed with titles. I've made a small edit to the citation style to avoid this. To disambiguate citations to multiple works by the same author(s)/editor(s), you can use the `shorttitle` field as I've done below. biblatex can (likely) be configured to perform disambiguation with `title`/`shorttitle` automatically, but since this is a one-off there isn't much point in pursuing such a feature.

```
\documentclass[nobib]{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=verbose,citepages=omit,dashed=false,maxcitenames=1]{biblatex}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{citetracker=true}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:short}{% based on cite:short from verbose.cbx
  \printtext[bibhyperlink]{\printnames{labelname}}%
  \iffieldundef{shorttitle}
    {}
    {\setunit*{\nametitledelim}%
     \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{bertram,
  author = {Bertram, Aaron and Wentworth, Richard},
  title = {Gromov invariants for holomorphic maps on Riemann surfaces},
  journaltitle = {J.~Amer. Math. Soc.},
  volume = {9},
  number = {2},
  date = {1996},
  pages = {529--571}}
@Book{companion,
  author = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and Samarin, Alexander},
  title = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location = {Reading, Mass.},
  date = {1994}}
@Book{poetics,
  author = {Aristotle},
  editor = {Lucas, D. W.},
  title = {Poetics},
  shorttitle = {Poetics},
  series = {Clarendon Aristotle},
  publisher = {Clarendon Press},
  location = {Oxford},
  date = {1968}}
@Book{rhetoric,
  author = {Aristotle},
  editor = {Cope, Edward Meredith},
  commentator = {Cope, Edward Meredith},
  title = {The Rhetoric of Aristotle with a commentary by the late Edward Meredith Cope},
  shorttitle = {Rhetoric},
  volumes = {3},
  publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
  date = {1877}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\section{First citations}

\subsection{Subsection}
First citation with pre- and postnotes
\autocite[See, for example][10--15]{companion}.

\subsection{Subsection}
First citation in a sidenote with only page reference;
pages field is omitted. \autocite[528--530]{bertram}

\subsection{Subsection}
First multi-citation
\autocites(Compare)()[10]{poetics}[528--530]{rhetoric}.

\section{Second citations}

\subsection{Subsection}
Second citation with only prenote
\autocite[See, for example,][]{companion}.

\subsection{Subsection}
Second citation; labelname is not unique so add a short title
to the .bib file \autocite{poetics}.

\subsection{Subsection}
Second citation; labelname is not unique so add a short title
to the .bib file \autocite[59--61]{rhetoric}.

Add a vertical offset before printing citation. Note that autocite
moves punctuation for you, but sidenote doesn't
\sidenote[][20pt]{\cite[See][\pno~570, last paragraph]{bertram}}.

\section*{References}
\printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Do I need the patch at http://code.google.com/p/tufte-latex/issues/detail?id=60 for this to work?

Comment: @David No, just the revised version (r173) of `tufte-common.def`. You can back up the original and save the revision in the folder `tex\latex\tufte-latex` of your `tex` installation. I already incorporated the relevant "patches" into the sample code above.

Comment: Thanks for this - it looks like just the thing I needed, but I'm having so much trouble getting it to work (my goodness, I didn't realise I was still using TL2007!), I think I'll have to just work things by hand this time around.