# \fullcite without indent in biblatex

Tags: spacing, biblatex

I'm using `\fullcite` to produce in-margin-note citations as per [my older question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24863/i-need-to-make-a-slightly-less-than-fullcite). I've almost got the behavior I want, but `biblatex`'s `\fullcite` command inserts a leading indent before the citation starts:

[image: example of space in weird place]

I'm using the `numeric` `biblatex` style. It's hard to generate a minimal example that generates this text because it relies on a recent version of [tufte-latex](http://code.google.com/p/tufte-latex), but refer to [tufte-latex Issue 60](http://code.google.com/p/tufte-latex/issues/detail?id=60).

Comment: You might have to provide a minimal example as it's not clear here if you are using the vanilla \fullcite. If you are using some sort of bibliography environment for the citations to do this, they you have to look at \bibhang etc. which are used to move indents and margins around when printing bibliography items.

Comment: @Alterscape I agree with PLK. I've tried this using the `tufte-book` class revisions and vanilla \fullcite. I don't get the indent.

Comment: @Audrey and PLK: I've gone through the modifications to my document and worked out what the cause is, but I don't know the fix. I'm editing my question to incorporate the new info.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, so the answer involves my misinterpretations of how the `\AtEveryCiteKey` definition works.  I had the following markup in my document, which I had formatted to be clear (to my C/Java/Ruby-writing programmer's mind) with newlines and indents:

```
\AtEveryCitekey{
  \clearfield{url}
  \clearfield{doi}
  \clearfield{isbn}
  \clearfield{issn}
}
```

LaTeX was interpreting the newlines as whitespace separated by (non-printing) characters, and adding four spaces to the beginning of every `\fullcite`!

I changed the markup to:

```
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{url}\clearfield{doi}\clearfield{isbn}\clearfield{issn}}
```

And now all is well.

Comment: To avoid very long lines, you can end each line in your first code excerpt [with the percent sign](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/4483).

Comment: It's not the leading tabs that TeX is pick up: it ignores leading whitespace. It's the newlines, which TeX is interpreting as spaces.

Comment: Many thanks for that, @Alterscape - I just bumped into the same problem, and solved it thanks to your posting. Just wanted to note, I was working with the code as in [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57095/2595); and discovered I have indents due to spaces _both_ before _and_ after the `\parseMyNum` call there (but in my case, from `\newbibmacro*`); which had to look like `^\parseMyNum{#1}% (all spaces removed)`, before all indentation would disappear! Furthermore, _none_ of the other commands seem to be so sensitive to whitespace?! Therefore, thanks again - and cheers!