# Can I use biblatex with Tufte classes?

Tags: biblatex, tufte

Is it possible to use biblatex with the Tufte document classes (tufte-handout and tufte-book). If so, what modifications should I make to my preamble or class wrapper in order to use biblatex?

---

I've tried the [recommended patch](http://code.google.com/p/tufte-latex/issues/detail?id=60) in a simple example:

```
\documentclass[nobib]{tufte-handout}

\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, natbib=true, style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References.bib}
\renewcommand{\cite}[2][0pt]{\sidenote[][#1]{\fullcite{#2}}}

\begin{document}

This,\cite{Sarukkai:2005} should be a side note and this\cite{Sarukkai:2005} should too.

\printbibliography 

\end{document}
```

But I don't get the results I should be getting (note the missing second citation):

[image]

(I'm also not sure how to combine this with the [modifications I've already made](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45878/7844) to support abbreviated citations after the first occurrence.)

Comment: There's some comments on this here: http://code.google.com/p/tufte-latex/issues/detail?id=60

Comment: @AlanMunn: I've added an example to show what happens when I do that.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Are you using the revised tufte-common.def? The link to it on that page is broken. Here's [another one](https://tufte-latex.googlecode.com/svn-history/r173/trunk/tufte-common.def).

Comment: @Audrey: With that the processing hangs.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Omit the redefinition of `cite`. I tried re-compiling the [document here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26084/4483) and the log is error-free.

Comment: @Audrey: Thanks. If I replace the `cite` redefinition above with [the one below](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45949/7844) I can get this MWE to work, using the 3.5.2 tufte-common.def (though with a biblatex warning about "Patching footnotes failed...Footnote detection will not work.") So I'm getting there, however when I try to adapt this to my workflow (LyX, following the [LyX instructions for using biblatex](http://wiki.lyx.org/BibTeX/Biblatex#toc2)) all I get is "naked" citekeys, as if the bibliography is not being built.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius You'll often get the footnote warning with packages that alter internal footnote commands. It's just saying that the biblatex test `\iffootnote` might not work as intended. I have no experience with LyX, so I can't help with your other issue.

Comment: @Audry: Ah! The problem with LyX is just that it is not finding the .bib file at all (because of a [path specification problem](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46550/7844)) and silently failing.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Rather than redefining the `\cite` command, I would use biblatex’s ability to let every citation go into a footnote (option `autocite=footnote`) which then will go into a sidenote (since tufte-latex uses the normal `\footnote` command for sidenotes). The following works for me with the [tufte-common.def 3.5.2](https://github.com/Tufte-LaTeX/tufte-latex/blob/master/tufte-common.def) from the tufte-latex svn repository. To override the original `def` file, just save the revised one as `$TEXMFHOME/tex/latex/tufte-latex/tufte-common.def`, where `$TEXMFHOME` is the path returned by `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME`.

```
\documentclass[nobib]{tufte-handout}

\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage[
  style=verbose,
  autocite=footnote,
  backend=biber
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

This,\autocite{springer} should be a side note and this\autocite{springer} should too.

\printbibliography 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This _sort of_ works for me. But in TeXShop, I can get this to work only (generally) after several attempts (for each build) using the "Bibliography" macro, but not the regular "Typeset" command. In LyX it won't build at all.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius, as I said: there are some error messages, so that LyX will stop compiling a PDF file. It seems as if the `nobib` option of the tufte class is not working correctly. However, I am not at all familiar with the tufte classes. Maybe you can file a bug report using the above example.

Comment: @domass: See Audrey's comment above, re: the 3.5.2 tuft-common.def.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius, thanks for the hint, I edited the answer accordingly (and can compile without errors now).

Comment: @Audrey: done (finally). I impudently made use of the wording in your [comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52471/error-using-tufte-book-class-and-biblatex#comment109693_52471).

Comment: @domwass Thanks. Again I prefer not to be acknowledged in edits - it just adds extraneous material the user doesn't need to see. With the `tufte-latex` classes, `biblatex` issues a warning about footnotes. I'm not sure how `\iffootnote` is affected, but the classes break `\smartcite` inside footnotes/sidenotes.

Comment: It might that various editors will throw errors, though the PDF will be produced. At leat this is true for Texpad.

Comment: The `tufte-comon.def` file is now available from https://github.com/Tufte-LaTeX/tufte-latex/blob/master/tufte-common.def . The SVN link is not working now.

Comment: I tried this solution, but could not get it to work.  Here is my MWE: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/656648/biblatex-sidenote-issue-with-tufte-book-class     Any help would be greatly appreciated!!