# Error using tufte-book class and biblatex

Tags: biblatex, tufte

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use biblatex with Tufte classes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45934/can-i-use-biblatex-with-tufte-classes)

Although there is a patch for using `biblatex` in the Tufte classes, it doesn't seem to work for me. First thing is, the `hyphenat` package produces an error stating that `\nohyphens` is already defined. Without the `hyphenat` package this error doesn't occur, but `biblatex.sty` instead states that `\bibhang`, `\bibfont` and `\citename` are already defined.

I guess the `nobib` option for `tufte-book` doesn't work properly and `natbib` clashes with `biblatex`. Is this possible? And what can I do?

```
\documentclass[nobib]{tufte-book}

\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage[
           style=authoryear
           ]{biblatex}
\bibliography{test.bib}


\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit \parencite{someone1900}.

\printbibliography 

\end{document}
```

---

First of all thank you for your fast answers.

Now you were right, I had the wrong `tufte-common.def`. I fixed that, but now the problem is that obviously the `hardwrap` package is also required. Since I use ubuntu linux and therefor don't have tlmgr, I installed tufte-latex by hand in the directory `/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex`, which works for tufte but not for the hardwrap package. So hardwrap has to be put somewhere else, but i don't know where.

Do you have an idea?

---

The ouput of `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME` states that this directory is located in my home directory. But this directory doesn't seem to exist, because I can't change to it: if I want to do that, i.e. change to the directory as it was located by `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME`, the system states that this directory doesn't exist.

Is it possible to leave the installation of `tufte-latex` intact and put the revised `tufte-common.def` in the directory I want to work in?

Comment: There is no support for `biblatex`.

Comment: Are you following the solution in [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45934/4483)? It requires use of [another](https://tufte-latex.googlecode.com/svn-history/r173/trunk/tufte-common.def) `tufte-common.def` file.

Comment: `hardwrap` shouldn't pose any problems if you leave your original installation of `tufte-latex` and required packages intact. To override the original `def` file, just save the revised one as `$TEXMFHOME/tex/latex/tufte-latex/tufte-common.def`, where `$TEXMFHOME` is the path returned by `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME`.

Comment: Don't ever install stuff yourself into directories managed by your package manager (in this case `/usr/share/`. This is a Really Bad Idea (TM).