# Biblatex / Biber full citation for first occurrence only

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber

I'm in the process of switching from BibTeX to BibLaTeX/biber. I've searched around but can't seem to find/figure out how to style the citations a particular way and I'd appreciate some help.

I'm using the tufte-latex package so citations appear in the margins. I'm looking to have the first occurrence of a citation give the full citation, i.e., Author, Title, publisher, year, and the remaining citations of that item simply give the numeric citation, i.e., author [citation number].

My current biblatex options are:

```
\usepackage[
natbib=true,
bibstyle=numeric, 
block=nbpar, 
citestyle=numeric, 
backend=biber
]{biblatex}
```

Two types of references are found in the text, the standard citation which appears as its own margin note, and a citation appearing within a margin note. To accommodate this I use the BibLaTeX commands `\textcite{}` for citations within a margin note (giving "Author [cit. number]"), and `\autocite{}` for standard citations with autocite being defined as follows.

```
\renewcommand{\autocite}[1]{\sidenote{\textcite{#1}}}
```

But again, what I would like is to have this set-up (or similar) but have the initial occurrence of each citation give the full citation (Author, title, pub, year, etc..) and the remainder go back to the numeric version I currently have.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using a modified [`tufte-common.def` file](https://tufte-latex.googlecode.com/svn-history/r173/trunk/tufte-common.def) you can create `tufte-latex` documents with `biblatex`. A limitation is that `tufte-latex` modifies footnotes. So `biblatex` features such as `\smartcite` inside footnotes and footnote detection with `\iffootnote` may not work as intended. Most of this has already been covered in [another post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45934/4483).

As for the citation style, you can get most of the way there with some edits to the `textcite` bibliography macro and `\smartcite`. Both of these are defined in `numeric.cbx`.

```
\documentclass[nobib]{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=numeric,citetracker=true,autocite=footnote]{biblatex}

\makeatletter

% If not seen, avoid compact lists and print full citation
\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
  \ifciteseen
    {}
    {\clearfield{namehash}}%
  \iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {\cbx@tempa
     \ifciteseen
       {\ifnameundef{labelname}
          {\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
          {\printnames{labelname}}}
       {\usedriver
          {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}%
           \clearfield{pages}%
           \clearfield{pagetotal}}
          {\thefield{entrytype}}}%
     \addspace\bibopenbracket}%
  \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{cite}%
  \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}%
  \gdef\cbx@tempa{\bibclosebracket\multicitedelim}}

% Make \smartcite like \textcite
\DeclareCiteCommand{\smartcite}[\iffootnote\mkbibbrackets\mkbibfootnote]
  {\let\cbx@tempa=\empty
   \undef\cbx@lasthash}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{textcite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}%
   \bibclosebracket}

\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
One of the most prominent and distinctive features of this style is the
extensive use of sidenotes \autocites(See)()[10--15]{knuth:ct:a}[10]{companion}.
There is a wide margin to provide ample room for sidenotes and small figures
\autocite{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b}. Any footnotes will automatically be converted to
sidenotes.\footnote{Results from \textcite{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b,companion} showed
that...}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Some notes:

- The `autocite=footnote` option setting makes `\autocite` use `\smartcite` as its backend citation command.
- The `\ifciteseen` test needs citation tracking enabled. In the example global tracking is enabled via `citetracker=true`. Alternative settings are possible. Refer to the manual for details.
- Full citations are printed with `\usedriver`. The first argument to this command allows you to hook code in before printing. This is a good place to suppress fields with `\clearfield` and friends. In the example, I suppress the `pages` and `pagetotal` fields to avoid confusion with page references in postnotes.
- In `numeric`, `\textcite` generates compact citation lists. This complicates printing full citations. The edits to `textcite` take an easy way out by simply replacing the `labelname` or `labeltitle` with the full citation.
- The `numeric` style isn't particularly suited to this customization. Refer to the `verbose` style or any of its variants for some better alternatives.