# First occurrence citation in margin note without explicit call

Tags: biblatex, citing, tufte, marginpar

I'm using the `tufte-book` document class and the `biblatex` package,
and would like to add margin notes indicating a
near-full reference the "first time" a citation is made. Specifically, I'd like for the in-text citation itself to act as a sort of note call. The closest
thing I've been able to achieve is:

[image]

Note two undesired things. First, the second margin note shouldn't exist. Second,
the margin note's citation information should be exactly the same as the
one in the main text. That is, no initials for first names.

I wrote *first time* between quotes because I'd like to reset the behavior for i) each page, ii) each even-odd pair of pages except the first page of the chapter which is odd (and should include the behavior), and iii) each chapter. Of course, only one case should hold for any complete document.

I tried, unsuccessfully, to adapt code from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35673/biblatex-is-there-a-command-analogous-to-ifciteseen-but-within-one-page), [here](https://www.texdev.net/2010/03/08/biblatex-numbered-citations-as-footnotes/), and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60383/biblatex-biber-full-citation-for-first-occurrence-only). I suspect two sources for the problem:

1) `citetracker` being disabled in all floats (p. 59 of the biblatex manual - version 3.11). I think the `marginfix` package arranges the margin notes using floats so I tried to set `\citetrackertrue` in several ways but all failed.

2) The `\newbibmacro*` section having incorrect syntax. More precisely, inside the `\ifciteseen` section.

Another strategy I tried was using `\AtEveryCitekey` to add additional code (`\marginnote{}`) the first time a key is used, but that didn't bring out the desired result.

Finally, please note I can't prescind from the `fixmargin` package, that I need to maintain APA style, and that I'm compiling with overleaf.com.

My minimal working example is:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{acemoglu2001colonial,
  title={The colonial origins of comparative development: An empirical investigation},
  author={Acemoglu, Daron and Johnson, Simon and Robinson, James A},
  journal={American Economic Review},
  volume={91},
  number={5},
  pages={1369--1401},
  year={2001}
}
\end{filecontents}

% ---------------------------------------

\documentclass[nobib]{tufte-book} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[
    style=apa,
    citestyle=apa,
    backend=biber
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{citetracker,sorting=none}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usedriver
     {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\newbibmacro*{fullcite}{%
  \ifciteseen
    {}
    {\fullcite{\thefield{entrykey}}\addperiod}
}

\usepackage{xargs}
\newcommandx{\mytextcite}[3][1={0pt},2={}]{
    \textcite{#3}\marginnote[#1]{\fullcite[#2]{#3}.}
    }

\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{pages}}
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{volume}}
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{number}}

% For Apa to work
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}

\usepackage{marginfix}

\begin{document}

\mytextcite{acemoglu2001colonial} argue that the evidence is not robust.

This new paragraph repeats a citation. We now want to check how repeated in-text citations are treated in the margin. \mytextcite{acemoglu2001colonial} are the only authors that \ldots

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does the style have to be based on `biblatex-apa` or would a standard style like `style=authoryear` also be OK? Since `biblatex-apa` has to work hard to implement all particularities of the APA guidelines it is harder to modify and tweak than the standard styles.

Comment: I would prefer it be APA. As you say, it does some convenient hard work. I don't know why it's necessary to tweak the APA style file, but a solution that is easy to implement and doesn't go all the way (mainly because the reference in the margin contains first name initials) is also welcome. I would rather not have those initials because a few characters can make a difference when many margin notes are laid out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see neither 1 nor 2 are actually problems here.

`biblatex`'s trackers are not disabled in `\marginnote` and the syntax for `\newbibmacro*{fullcite}` is actually correct, but there is no bibmacro called `fullcite` and it is never called, so that definition doesn't do anything.

But there is a problem with the proposed approach. `\mytextcite` is split into two different and separate cite commands (`\textcite` and `\fullcite`). Naturally these two commands have different values for `\ifciteseen`. If a citation has not been seen before `\textcite` has `\ifciteseen` switched to false, but toggles it to true for all subsequent citations. That means no matter what `\ifciteseen` will be true for the subsequent `\fullcite`.

The best way to get out of this problem is to define only one cite command with `\DeclareCiteCommand` that decides whether or not to issue a margin note directly. That way the `\ifciteseen` has the correct value.

The second change I applied is a matter of taste. Instead of using fullcite and deleting 'superfluous' information with `\AtEveryCitekey` I found it more elegant to define a macro that only prints the desired information in the first place. `nearfullcite` shows the labelname (author, editor, etc.), year, title and title of the enclosing work (`journaltitle` or `booktitle`) if appropriate.

Because you want to use `biblatex-apa` the code needed a few dirty hacks. `bibaltex-apa` has to work really hard to get some of the APA requirements right and it can be a pain to interfere with that.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{acemoglu2001colonial,
  title   = {The colonial origins of comparative development: An empirical investigation},
  author  = {Acemoglu, Daron and Johnson, Simon and Robinson, James A},
  journal = {American Economic Review},
  volume  = {91},
  number  = {5},
  pages   = {1369--1401},
  year    = {2001}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[nobib]{tufte-book} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[
    style=apa,
    citetracker=true,
    backend=biber,
]{biblatex}

\newcommand*{\bibmarginnote}[2][0pt]{%
  \marginnote[#1]{\protecting{\blxmkbibnote{foot}{#2}}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\margtextcite}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{textcite}%
   \ifciteseen
     {}
     {\bibmarginnote{\usebibmacro{nearfullcite}}}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:post}}

\newrobustcmd*{\Margtextcite}{\bibsentence\margtextcite}

\makeatletter
% this macro is specific to biblatex-apa
\newbibmacro*{nearfullcite}{%
  \begingroup
  \let\ifciteseen\@secondoftwo% <- bad hack for biblatex-apa
  \printnames[labelname][-\value{listtotal}]{labelname}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{cite:paren:labeldate+extradate}%
  \newunit
  \ifbooklikeentrytype
    {\usebibmacro{maintitle+title}} 
    {\usebibmacro{title}}%
  \newunit
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {\usebibmacro{journal}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \ifinbooklikeentrytype
    {\usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}}
    {}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\providebibmacro*{cite:paren:labeldate+extradate}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{\printlabeldateextra}}}

\newcommand*{\ifbooklikeentrytype}{%
  \ifboolexpr{   test {\ifentrytype{book}}
              or test {\ifentrytype{collection}}
              or test {\ifentrytype{proceedings}}}}

\newcommand*{\ifinbooklikeentrytype}{%
  \ifboolexpr{   test {\ifentrytype{inbook}}
              or test {\ifentrytype{incollection}}
              or test {\ifentrytype{inproceedings}}}}

\newcommand*{\ifmisclikeentrytype}{%
  \ifboolexpr{   test {\ifentrytype{booklet}}
              or test {\ifentrytype{manual}}
              or test {\ifentrytype{misc}}
              or test {\ifentrytype{online}}
              or test {\ifentrytype{report}}
              or test {\ifentrytype{thesis}}
              or test {\ifentrytype{unpublished}}}}

\usepackage{marginfix}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\Margtextcite{acemoglu2001colonial,sigfridsson,nussbaum} argue that the evidence is not robust.

This new paragraph repeats a citation. We now want to check how repeated in-text citations are treated in the margin. It has been shown by \margtextcite{acemoglu2001colonial,geer,sigfridsson} that \ldots

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

The cite tracker can be reset on a per-chapter (if available), per-section, per-subsection basis with the option `citereset=chapter` etc. etc.

For a per-page reset there is no `citereset` there you just use `\iflastciteonsamepage` from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/275524/35864 instead of `\ifciteseen`.