# How to include page numbers in tufte-book citations?

Tags: citing, tufte

Using the [tufte-latex package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tufte-latex), the tufte-book class replaces the page argument from the cite command with a positioning argument, therefore impariring the possibility of citing pages. Is there a way to go around it an keep citing with pages?

The normal way of using tufte-book without pages is like this:

tufte-mwe.tex :

```
\documentclass{tufte-book} 
\begin{document} 
A citation\cite{Tufte2001}. 
\bibliography{tufte-mwe} 
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} 
\end{document}
```

tufte-mwe.bib:

```
@BOOK{Tufte2001,
    author = {Edward R. Tufte},
    title = {The Visual Display of Quantitative Information},
    publisher = {Graphics Press},
    year = {2001},
    address = {Cheshire, Connecticut},
    isbn = {0-9613921-4-2}
}
```

Produces this:
[image: Normal tufte-book citation]

But using cite to insert page numbers like this:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book} 
\begin{document} 
A citation\cite[p.50]{Tufte2001}. 
\bibliography{tufte-mwe} 
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} 
\end{document}
```

Doesn't work and produces this: [image: tufte-book with page numbers]

This is because the tufte-book class expects a measure of position and not a page number (to append to the citation) as an argument.

Thanks.

edit: added mwe and precisions

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I don't know how it works in `natbib` but I think you can add the pages field in your reference, and then maybe they'll appear in your citation.

Comment: Thanks, Aradnix, you're right. But that doesn't work to reference a specific page within a reference, a book page for instance.

Comment: You can use ´biblatex´. There is a related question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45934). The patch is described on the original [tufte page](https://code.google.com/p/tufte-latex/issues/detail?id=60).

Comment: Thanks for the reference. It works, with a modification of the renewcommand for cite. Also, the package version in CRAN is older than the sources, you need to go to the sources directly.

Comment: @Andy could you update the links because I encounter the same problems as Erispoe and I cannot solve them, or answer to my question : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/539354/how-to-include-page-number-in-citations-in-a-tufte-book-document-class. Thanks !

Comment: @Erispoe could you please insert your modification of the renewcommand for cite in a mimimal working example (MWE) because I have the same problem as you, but I don't understand what to do...

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer at the following question:
[How to include page number in citations in a Tufte-Book document class?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/539354/how-to-include-page-number-in-citations-in-a-tufte-book-document-class/547504#547504)