# How to include page number in citations in a Tufte-Book document class?

Tags: citing, tufte

I have the same problem as presented in this question :
[How to include page numbers in tufte-book citations?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205373/how-to-include-page-numbers-in-tufte-book-citations)

Unfortunatly, the person who asked the question found the solution without publishing the answer.
Who can specify the elements to add in the `MWE`:

tufte-mwe.tex :

```
\documentclass{tufte-book} 
\usepackage{babelbib}
\begin{document} 
A citation\cite[p.50]{Tufte2001}. 
\bibliography{tufte-mwe} 
\bibliographystyle{plain-fr} 
\end{document}
```

tufte-mwe.bib:

```
@BOOK{Tufte2001,
author = {Edward R. Tufte},
title = {The Visual Display of Quantitative Information},
publisher = {Graphics Press},
year = {2001},
address = {Cheshire, Connecticut},
isbn = {0-9613921-4-2}
}
```

as this code produces bad result as follow, instead of specifying the page of the reference in the sidenote :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution :

```
\documentclass[nobib]{tufte-book}
\usepackage[french]{babel}%.................. Language setup
\usepackage[htt]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authortitle-icomp]{biblatex}% It is possible to change the style, see http://ctan.tetaneutral.net/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf
\addbibresource{tufte-mwe.bib}
\begin{document}
A citation\footcite[50]{Tufte2001}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: With `biblatex` you should not (need to) add the `p.` bit to the page number. `\cite[50]{Tufte2001}` or `\cite[50-52]{Tufte2001}` is enough. `biblatex` will automatically add "p."/"pp." (or a localised version if you write in a language other than English and load babel) as appropriate.

Comment: In that case `\cite[50]{Tufte2001}` should definitely be enough to get "p. 50" in the output.

Comment: is the [htt] option of the hyphenat package necessary when using this solution?  Why are you using the [htt] option?

Comment: @Steven You're  right, the [htt] option of the hyphenat package seems useless. I had to copy the solution from an answer found elsewhere (I don't know what this option is for...I'm not a developer).

Comment: @Phil8544 compiling the MWE here does not include the page number at all in the citation as far as i can tell. what is it supposed to look like?

Comment: @failedentertainment I use \autocite[p.~58]{Tufte2001} and it works well in my document (sorry for the delay of my answer...).

Comment: @Phil8544 I tried your MWE with footcite and autocite and neither version includes the page number in the PDF.

Comment: I use XeLateX, perhaps it is the compilation mode... ? It works well on my document.