# How to make short citations in text while leaving full citations in a bibliography section?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, tufte

I want to make footnote citations within a main text in shorter format, while having full versions in a bibliography section in the end.

For example, to omit article titles in footnotes, only to leave authors, year, journal issue:

> Grmela & Öttinger, Phys. Rev. E 56 A997) 6620;

and in the bibliography still have:

> Miroslav Grmela and Hans Christian Öttinger. Dynamics and thermodynamics of complex fluids. I. Development of a general formalism. Phys. Rev. E 56 A997) 6620-6632.

How do I achieve this (if this is achievable in BibTeX)? I think it is also important that I use `tufte-book` document class.

I'm new to BibTeX and I don't see any official manual around to help.

Comment: The BibTeX documentation is available at http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/doc/

Comment: I would recommend to consider biblatex (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45934/can-i-use-biblatex-with-tufte-classes). Then, it would be much easier to achieve.

Comment: Without knowing the style and general setup, this question is impossible to answer properly. I vote to close.