# Is it possible to fine-tune the citation positions in Tufte-BibLaTeX combination?

Tags: biblatex, tufte

I'm using tufte-latex in combination with BibLaTeX, as described in  [Can I use biblatex with Tufte classes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45934/can-i-use-biblatex-with-tufte-classes?lq=1) and I have tried the variants suggested both in the question and in the answer. Using the variant based on biblatex's option `autocite=footnote`, I get nicer results, with shorter version of the citation when it's used more than once, but I don't have the ability to fine-tune the position of the sidenote with the citation, as in the case of redefining the `cite` command. On the other hand, the redefined `cite` command always provides me the full version of citation, and the margins quickly become overflooded with citations.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[nobib]{tufte-handout}

\usepackage{hyphenat}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
autocite=footnote,
citecounter=true, 
style=verbose,
citetracker=true
]{biblatex}

%redefinition of cite command
\renewcommand{\cite}[2][0pt]{\sidenote[][#1]{\fullcite{#2}}}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

This,\autocite{springer} should be a side note and this\autocite{springer} should too.

This,\cite{springer} should be a side note and this\cite[2cm]{springer} should be a shifted down side note.

\printbibliography 

\end{document}
```

**Output:**
[image: MWE output]

So my question is: is it possible somehow to get controllable position for the sidenotes generated with the `autocite` command?

Comment: Can you provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) that shows both how you use `\cite` and `\autocite`?

Comment: Also: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Yes, I've just added it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One (at least I find) elegant and quite usable way would be a new command, say `\sidecite`.

It will use the same syntax as all the `\cite` command, but features an optional offset argument enclosed in `<>` at the beginning.

We will use [`xparse`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse) to implement it.

First we copy the definition of `\footcite` from the relevant `.cbx` style file (in your case `verbose.cbx`), rename it to `\sidecitehelper` and replace `\mkbibfootnote` by `\bibfootnotewrapper` (so we don't actually get a footnote, but consistent output).

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\sidecitehelper}[\bibfootnotewrapper]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}%
   \toggletrue{blx@footnote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}
```

Then we define `\sidecite`

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\sidecite{D<>{}O{}om}{%
  \iftoggle{blx@footnote}
    {\cs_set_protected_nopar:Npn \__sct_wrapper:nn ##1 ##2 {\mkbibparens{##2}}}
    {\cs_set_protected_nopar:Npn \__sct_wrapper:nn ##1 ##2 {\sidenote[][##1]{##2}}}
    {\IfNoValueTF{#3}
      {\__sct_wrapper:nn{#1}{\sidecitehelper[#2]{#4}}}
      {\__sct_wrapper:nn{#1}{\sidecitehelper[#2][#3]{#4}}}}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

With this updated definition of `\sidecite` we now check if we are in a side note (footnote) and if so only wrap the citation in parentheses instead of creating nested foot/side notes.
We have a dummy command `\__sct_wrapper:nn` that in footnotes just wraps things in parentheses and outside of footnotes creates a side note.
In `biblatex` the command `\mkbibfootnote` takes care of that, and if we hadn't wanted `\sidenote` to be able to take its optional argument, an approach with a wrapper command mirroring `\mkbibfootnote` would have been easier; but since we need the optional argument, all this handling has been moved to `\sidecite`.

There is one problem left with that: `tufte-latex`'s `\footnote` command can by default not be patched by `biblatex`, so we need to do that ourselves.
We use [`xpatch`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch) for that

```
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@footnotetext}%
      {\color@begingroup}
      {\color@begingroup\toggletrue{blx@footnote}}
      {}
      {}
\makeatother
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[nobib]{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[
  style=verbose,
  autocite=footnote,
  backend=biber
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@footnotetext}%
      {\color@begingroup}
      {\color@begingroup\toggletrue{blx@footnote}}
      {}
      {}
\makeatother

\DeclareCiteCommand{\sidecitehelper}[\bibfootnotewrapper]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\sidecite{D<>{}O{}om}{%
  \iftoggle{blx@footnote}
    {\cs_set_protected_nopar:Npn \__sct_wrapper:nn ##1 ##2 {\mkbibparens{##2}}}
    {\cs_set_protected_nopar:Npn \__sct_wrapper:nn ##1 ##2 {\sidenote[][##1]{##2}}}
    {\IfNoValueTF{#3}
      {\__sct_wrapper:nn{#1}{\sidecitehelper[#2]{#4}}}
      {\__sct_wrapper:nn{#1}{\sidecitehelper[#2][#3]{#4}}}}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

This,\sidecite[8]{springer} should\autocite{springer} be a side note and this\sidecite[see][8]{springer} should too.

Lorem ipsum\sidecite<2cm>[9]{geer} dolor\sidecite[cf.][]{springer}.

Sit\sidenote{amet \sidecite{geer}}.

\printbibliography 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note the 2cm offset of footnote 3 (`\sidecite<2cm>[9]{geer}`), as well as the natural "if there is only one optional argument, it is the postnote" behaviour standard `biblatex` cite commands in footnote 1 (`\sidecite[8]{springer}`).
The `\sidecite` in footnote 6 (`\sidenote{amet \sidecite{geer}}`) becomes a citation in parentheses to avoid nested footnotes.

Comment: I have only one remark -- actually, I wanted to use this special command only on a couple of difficult pages; and to leave autocite elsewhere, but I noticed that than autocite do not correlate with sidecite. Try to change the first sidecite in your MWE
    `This,\autocite[8]{springer} should be a side note and   this\sidecite[see][8]{springer} should too.`

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "they do not correlate". I have, however, made an edit that should make citation tracking more "smooth", maybe that is what you are after.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear -- I meant the `sidecite` doesn't see that the citation has been already called by `autocite` and produces full citation instead of abbreviated one. 
What have you edited? --I cannot spot the difference

Comment: @OlegSoloviev I had inserted a `\toggletrue{blx@footnote}` into the pre-code of `\sidecitehelper`. I have, however, just edited a slightly greater change to the code, you might want to try that.

Comment: you're a true biblatex-wizard! I'm thinking now to post a couple more questions on the same topic...

I haven't noticed the `\toggletrue{blx@footnote}` yesterday (it was not in the MWE), everything works fine for me if I add this line to the prenote of `\sidecitehelper`, although it's not surrounded by `\makeatletter`-`\makeatother` pair.

With the new version of the code everything works as well, but the code itself is beyond my understanding... I guess it's adapted for some broader purposes, could you explain them briefly if possible?

Comment: @OlegSoloviev The new definition aims to reproduce `biblatex`'s behaviour of avoiding nested footnotes (it was actually only a bit of fun). In the edit I have tried to explain what happens, but ask away if you want anything explained in more detail.

Comment: Fantastic! It would be great if this becomes part of the tufte classes.

Comment: This solution worked great for me. Thank you!  Also, if anyone needs to know how to modify the tufte epigraph command to make it work with biblatex in this whole context,  this may help:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/656648/biblatex-sidenote-issue-with-tufte-book-class

Comment: I have a related issue that I am trying to solve.  I have posted a MWE at this link:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/657138/tufte-latex-vertical-adjustment-of-biblatex-citations-in-captions