# problem with the cite at the bottom of the page

Tags: citing, tufte, marginnote, sidenotes

I am using Tufte-style template. When use a citation at the bottom of page, the cited text crosses the margin of the page.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,nohyper]{tufte-book} %abstracton
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2] \sidenote{\lipsum[3]}
\lipsum[1-2] \sidenote{\lipsum[2]}
\lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I have already tried the solution given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238661/is-it-possible-to-fine-tune-the-citation-positions-in-tufte-biblatex-combination) but doesn't work in my case.
Please suggest a solution. Thank you

Comment: The link in your question is broken. Please correct it. (I don't know what it should be.)

Answer (score 4):

You can adjust the vertical position of the note using the optional argument. This is covered on pages 21-22 of `sample-book.pdf`, part of the documentation for the class.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,nohyper]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2] \sidenote{\lipsum[3]}
\lipsum[1-2] \sidenote[][-60pt]{\lipsum[2]}
\lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

[image: modified note position]

## EDIT

If you have a lot of marginal material which would need manual adjustment, you have a couple of options. First, you can do it manually if you do so *after* the document content is finalised. Don't do it earlier because changes to the document content will alter what is required.

However, it might be better to look for more automated support. Although Tufte does not offer this, other classes do. Here is the same example using `memoir` and without the need for manual adjustment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2] \sidefootnote{\lipsum[3]}
\lipsum[1-2] \sidefootnote{\lipsum[2]}
\lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

[image: memoir]

Memoir offers extensive support for marginal material of various kinds, including side bars which run to multiple pages, floating and non-floating marginal material and support for marginal 'foot'notes.

KOMA might also be useful but, unfortunately, the English documentation does not include this topic so I cannot tell one way or another.

Comment: It works perfectly for the given case but for example I can not do it with every citation or margin text because if later I update this document by adding/removing some text or a float environment (table or figure) then it may not be aligned with the text or could lead to problem with the top of the page.**Is there any way to make margin text adaptive to the vertical margins?**

Comment: @aly This is basically the mechanism provided by the class. Regardless, these are manual tweaks which you should only do when the document content is finalised, I think. A bit like giving LaTeX help by manually inserting page breaks: you only do that right at the end precisely because stuff will change. There is a package called `needspace` but I am not sure if it could be used here. Tufte is not always compatible with packages designed for standard classes and, besides, this is not regular text.... I'll have a look, though.

Comment: @aly Have you considered using `memoir` (or, maybe, one of the KOMA classes)? `memoir` has extensive support for different kinds of marginal material and supports controlling it in different ways.

Comment: @aly See edit for an example with Memoir which seems to do this really nicely.

Comment: I appreciate your detailed response. I need to stick to Tufte-Class and will try to use needspace package.