# Combine fnpct with tufte's sidenote incl offset-adjust?

Tags: tufte, fnpct

I would like to combine the benefits of fnpct with the tufte-book document 
class. I heavily rely on manually adjusting some footnotes according to

```
\sidenote[][1cm]{my sidenote text}
```

in the tufte document class because my document contains a lot of margin material.
Unfortunately, I get an error when trying this together with fnpct (according to Figure 9 in [this document](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fnpct/fnpct_en.pdf)).

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}
\usepackage[multiple]{fnpct}
\AdaptNote\sidenote\multsidenote
\begin{document}
Some text in the document body\sidenote[][1cm]{Some 6 text in a sidenote.}.
\end{document}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269500/how-to-combine-fnpct-with-offset-adjustable-footcite-command) is similar but many even more involved, hence my simple MWE. I tried playing around with the AdaptNote command but no luck so far.

Answer (score 1):

Using the suggested `\AdaptNote\sidenote\multsidenote` gives me the following error `! File ended while scanning use of \__fnpct_read_note_with_option:w`.

The following options do work:

```
\usepackage{fnpct}
% kerning without multiple notes
\AdaptNoteOptNoMult\sidenote
```

and

```
\usepackage{fnpct}
% kerning with multiple notes, yet no multiple footnotemarks
\AdaptNoteOpt\sidenote\multsidenote
```

Following this logic I would assume this last examples works as well, but it raises the same error as the suggested commands in the `fnpct` manual.

```
\usepackage[multiple]{fnpct}
% errors
\AdaptNoteOpt\sidenote\multsidenote
```

Answer (score 0):

As of v1.0 `fnpct` is compatible with `tufte-latex`'s `\sidenote`:

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{fnpct}
\begin{document}

Some text in the document body\sidenote{text}\sidenote[][1cm]{Some 6 text in a
  sidenote.}.

\end{document}
```

[image]