# \sidecites command for biblatex and Tufte LaTeX?

Tags: biblatex, tufte

[A terrific answer to a question about fine-tuning citation positions with the Tufte-BibLaTeX combination](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238661/is-it-possible-to-fine-tune-the-citation-positions-in-tufte-biblatex-combination) provided a \sidecite command with an optional offset parameter.  It works like a charm.

Can someone show me how to define the analogous \sidecites command?  I'd like to write something like `\sidecites<1cm> {foo} [1]{bar}`, if possible.

Comment: While an answer is being cooked up, the way the linked-to answer looks to me means that `\sidecite{<entry1>,<entry2>}` will work mostly fine.