# Consistent punctuation with custom cite command

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, biber

I am using the solution from [Is it possible to fine-tune the citation positions in Tufte-BibLaTeX combination?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238661/is-it-possible-to-fine-tune-the-citation-positions-in-tufte-biblatex-combination/238673#238673) which works nearly perfect. However the punctuation at the end of the citation is not consistent with `\autocite`.

In the following MWE, the first citation has no `.` at the end, but the second one has.

```
\documentclass[nobib]{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[
  style=verbose,
  autocite=footnote,
  backend=biber
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@footnotetext}%
      {\color@begingroup}
      {\color@begingroup\toggletrue{blx@footnote}}
      {}
      {}
\makeatother

\DeclareCiteCommand{\sidecitehelper}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\sidecite{D<>{}O{}om}{%
  \iftoggle{blx@footnote}
    {\cs_set_protected_nopar:Npn \__sct_wrapper:nn ##1 ##2 {\mkbibparens{##2}}}
    {\cs_set_protected_nopar:Npn \__sct_wrapper:nn ##1 ##2 {\sidenote[][##1]{##2}}}
    {\IfNoValueTF{#3}
      {\__sct_wrapper:nn{#1}{\sidecitehelper[#2]{#4}}}
      {\__sct_wrapper:nn{#1}{\sidecitehelper[#2][#3]{#4}}}}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

This,\sidecite[8]{springer} should\autocite{springer} be a side note
\printbibliography 

\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I make `\sidecite` consistent with `\autocite`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make `\sidecite` consistent with `\footcite` we can add `\bibfootnotewrapper` to the wrapper command (originally we removed `\mkbibfootnote`, but with `\bibfootnotewrapper` we retain consistency)

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\sidecitehelper}[\bibfootnotewrapper]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}
```

I have also changed my original answer to include this modification.