# Biblatex sidenote issue with Tufte-Book Class

Tags: biblatex, tufte, sidenotes, tufte-book

I followed the solution to the best of my ability as found in this link: [Can I use biblatex with Tufte classes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45934/can-i-use-biblatex-with-tufte-classes)

However, I am still having an issue with getting the side notes to properly show up in the margin.  Here is my MWE:

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}
\RequirePackage[hyphens]{url}
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,nobib]{tufte-book}
\hypersetup{colorlinks, citecolor=blue}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[T5,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[
style=verbose,
autocite=footnote,
sorting=nty,
citecounter=true,
citetracker=true,
backref=true,
backend=biber
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{HSFSS-BIBLATEX.bib}
\newcommand{\openepigraph}[2]{%
  \begin{fullwidth}
  \sffamily\small
  \begin{doublespace}
  \noindent\allcaps{#1}\\% epigraph
  \noindent\allcaps{#2}% author
  \end{doublespace}
  \end{fullwidth}
}%
\begin{document}
\openepigraph{
Is England and nowhere. Never and always.
}{—T.S. Eliot\autocite{TSEliot}
}
\vfill
\openepigraph{
The Sky is blue.
}{—Author\autocite{Tufte2001}}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Here is my .bib file:

```
@MISC{tseliot,
    author = {Eltiot, T. S.},
    title = {\textit{Four Quartets}{ | Quartet No. 4: Little Gidding}},
    date = {},
    note = {December 2013 [Accessed 27 January 2022]},
    howpublished = {\url{http://davidgorman.com/4quartets/4-gidding.htm}}
}

@BOOK{Tufte2001,
    author = {Edward R. Tufte},
    title = {The Visual Display of Quantitative Information},
    publisher = {Graphics Press},
    year = {2001},
    address = {Cheshire, Connecticut},
    isbn = {0-9613921-4-2}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a modified definition of `\openepigraph`

`\openepigraph{<epigraph>}{<author>}{\autocite{<to author work>}}`

[image: b]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}
\RequirePackage[hyphens]{url}

\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,nobib]{tufte-book}   

\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[T5,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}   

\usepackage[
style=verbose,
autocite=footnote,
sorting=nty,
citecounter=true,
citetracker=true,
backref=true,
backend=biber
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{HSFSS-BIBLATEX.bib}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{HSFSS-BIBLATEX.bib}
@MISC{tseliot,
    author = {Eltiot, T. S.},
    title = {\textit{Four Quartets}{ | Quartet No. 4: Little Gidding}},
    date = {},
    note = {December 2013 [Accessed 27 January 2022]},
    howpublished = {\url{http://davidgorman.com/4quartets/4-gidding.htm}}
}

@BOOK{Tufte2001,
    author = {Edward R. Tufte},
    title = {The Visual Display of Quantitative Information},
    publisher = {Graphics Press},
    year = {2001},
    address = {Cheshire, Connecticut},
    isbn = {0-9613921-4-2}
}
@book{knuth97,
    address = {Reading, Mass.},
    author = {Knuth, Donald E.},        
    edition = {Third},
    isbn = {0201896834 9780201896831},
    publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
    title = {The Art of Computer Programming, Vol. 1: Fundamental Algorithms},
    year = {1997}
}

\end{filecontents}


\newcommand{\openepigraph}[3]{% changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \begin{fullwidth}
        \sffamily\large
        \begin{doublespace}
            \noindent\allcaps{#1}\\% epigraph
            \noindent\allcaps{#2}#3% author & autocite
        \end{doublespace}%
    \end{fullwidth}
}

\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}   

    \openepigraph{Is England and nowhere. Never and always.}{---T.S. Eliot}{\autocite{tseliot}}
    
    \vfill
    
    \openepigraph{The Sky is blue.}{---Author}{\autocite{Tufte2001}}    
    
    \vfill
    
    \openepigraph{%
        \ldots the designer of a new system must not only be the implementor and the first 
        large-scale user; the designer should also write the first user manual\ldots 
        If I had not participated fully in all these activities, 
        literally hundreds of improvements would never have been made, 
        because I would never have thought of them or perceived 
        why they were important.
    }{---Donald E. Knuth}{\autocite{knuth97}}
    
    \printbibliography
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you!

Comment: The tufte-book class allows for the vertical position adjustment of sidenotes (footnotes are converted to sidenotes in the class). I have figured out that this is a custom modification of the options of the footnote and/or cite command within the tufte-book class?  But, now that I am using biblatex and its associated options, it appears that this functionality is no longer working?  Normally, using the native tufte class, the option is defined like this:  \cite[1in]{bibkey] as an example.  Is there an easy fix or modification for this if one is using biblatex?

Comment: It appears I have just answered my previous question with this link:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238661/is-it-possible-to-fine-tune-the-citation-positions-in-tufte-biblatex-combination/238673#238673