# Short author list in sidenote citations, full list in references

Tags: bibliographies, citing, tufte

In the Tufte handouts style, how can I `cite` a reference such that the corresponding side note cuts the author list to "First Author et al." when there are more than 2 authors? In the bibliography at the end of the document I would like the entry to contain the full list of authors.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex) package: It allows controlling the number of displayed authors in citations and bibliographies separately using the `maxcitenames` and `maxbibnames` options.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually in this case they are both bibliography entries (no citation), but one is shown in the margin

Comment: Technically you are right, but the `biblatex` package uses a citestyle similar to the bibliography entry when putting citations in footnotes (i.e. marginnotes in `tufte-latex`). If you extend this answer (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45949/93842) with the `maxcitenames` and `maxbibnames` options, you can achieve exactly what you want.