# tufte-book + biblatex error: biblatex incompatible with natbib?

Tags: biblatex, tufte

I would like to compile a thesis with the [tufte-book](https://github.com/Tufte-LaTeX/tufte-latex) class. Is tufte-book supposed to be compatible with biblatex? [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45934/can-i-use-biblatex-with-tufte-classes) suggests that it's possible? Maybe something changed since?

Here's a MWE:

```tex
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage[style=verbose, autocite=footnote, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{../references.bib}

\begin{document}

Hello World.

\end{document}
```

The error is:

```
! Package biblatex Error: Incompatible package 'natbib'.

See the biblatex package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.202 \blx@packageincompatibility

?
```

I tried using both Tectonic and `pdflatex` which the authors of [tufte-book recommend in their README](https://github.com/Tufte-LaTeX/tufte-latex#quick-start). [This GitHub issue of tufte-latex](https://github.com/christopheradams/tufte-latex/issues/60) suggests that they wish to switch to biblatex from natbib?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `tufte-latex` classes load `natbib` by default and `natbib` is completely incompatible with `biblatex` (because `natbib` is based on the classical BibTeX and core-LaTeX approach to citations and bibliographies while `biblatex` completely reimplements citation and bibliography handling).

If you load `tufte-book` with the option `nobib`, it will not load `natbib` and you can use `biblatex`. (Note that both the question and answer in [Can I use biblatex with Tufte classes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45934/35864) use the `nobib` option, but don't discuss its relevance explicitly.)

```
\documentclass[nobib]{tufte-book}
\usepackage[style=verbose, autocite=footnote, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Hello World.\autocite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Tufte with citation in margin]

Note that with `biblatex` you need to compile your document with Biber and not with BibTeX ([Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) might be helpful).

Comment: Thanks! I tried now to use `biditufte-book` and I used the `nobib` option and I still get the same errors as before.

Comment: @DoronBehar `biditufte-book` (as included in `bidi`) appears to be based on an ancient version of `tufte-latex` (from before `2011/06/18`) that doesn't support the `noibid` option.

Comment: @DoronBehar That said, I can't even get `\documentclass{biditufte-book}
\begin{document}Hello World\end{document}` to compile without error with a current LaTeX kernel, so you may have other problems here.