# documentclass tufte-latex produces error messages with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, luatex, tufte

Using the documentclass `tufte-book` with `biblatex` requires seemingly the option `[nobib]` [following this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/587605/tufte-book-biblatex-error-biblatex-incompatible-with-natbib). Using a current version of lualatex

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.15.0 (TeX Live 2022/Debian)  (format=lualatex 2023.6.17)  29 JUN 2023 15:24
 restricted system commands enabled.
```

and the versions of `tufte-book` from github the desired `pdf` are produced but I have a number of error messages (and sometimes no output). What needs to be changed in my MVE:

```
\documentclass[nobib]  {tufte-handout}  

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{microtype} 
\renewcommand{\allcapsspacing}[1]{\textls[200]{#1}}% 
\renewcommand{\smallcapsspacing}[1]{\textls[50]{#1}}%

 \usepackage[backend=biber,
     style=authoryear,
     autocite=footnote,
     ]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{xxxxxxx/BibTexLatex.bib}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

With a reference to \autocite{frank09geo} and 
  unpublished \autocite{hamster11}. 
 
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The error messages start with

```
Argument of \MakeLowercase has an extra }.
Paragraph ended before \MakeLowercase was complete.
Paragraph ended before \MakeLowercase was complete.
```

...

My bib entries are:

```
@Unpublished{hamster11,
  author    = {Andrew U. Frank},
  date      = {2011-02-11},
  title     = {User Manual for {HAMSTER}},
  abstract  = {Hamster deals with three issues of importance.},
  file      = {docs/docsH/Manual_GUI.pdf},
  owner     = {frank},
  timestamp = {2018.11.30},
  year      = {2011},
}
@InProceedings{frank09geo,
  author    = {Frank, Andrew U.},
  title     = {Geo-Ontologies Are Scale Dependent (abstract only)},
  booktitle = {European Geosciences Union, General Assembly 2009, Session Knowledge and Ontologies},
  year      = {2009},
  editor    = {Pulkkinen, Tuija},
  url       = {http://publik.tuwien.ac.at/files/PubDat-175453.pdf},
  file      = {docs/docs4/4698_GeoOntologies_abstarct_EUG_09.pdf},
  groups    = {authorAF},
  keywords  = {Onto},
  owner     = {frank},
  timestamp = {2018.11.29},
}
```

Comment: `\renewcommand{\textsc}[1]{\smallcapsspacing{\textsmallcaps{#1}}}`

Comment: Perfect! works immediately. @UlrikeFischer I assume the recommendation is similar to what you wrote in my pull request. Thank you!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do you want to type up a quick answer here, so that the question can be marked as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer @UlrikeFischer worked perfectly. Just add:

\renewcommand{\textsc}[1]{\smallcapsspacing{\textsmallcaps{#1}}}