# Short citation and biblatex in tufte-class

Tags: biblatex, natbib, tufte

I am using the `tufte-book` class and want to have short citations, e.g. only first author, year, and maybe title, rather than a full cite every time I cite a reference. Various solutions suggest to use the `[nobib]` option to suppress `natbib` and then use `biblatex`. Unfortunately, `[nobib]` doesn't seem to do anything and I still get compatibility issues when using it with `biblatex`. One workaround would be to define my own citation command akin to

```
\sidenote{\citet{}}
```

This allows for short references in the margins, yet I still can't get biblatex to work. The solutions I found here didn't help.

**Edit:** That's the code that doesn't work.

```
\documentclass[nobib]{tufte-book} % Use the tufte-book class which in turn uses the tufte-common class

\usepackage[style=alphabetic,
            backend=bibtex8,        % or use biber or bibtex?
            bibencoding=latin1, % .bib file in latin1 or utf8 encoding?
            maxbibnames=99,         % give full list of authors (up to 99) in bibliography
            giveninits=true,        % use only initials for the first names
            url=false               % don't display urls
            ]{biblatex}
\bibliography{references}

\newcommand{\mycite}[1]{\sidenote{\citet{#1}}}


\begin{document}


\chapter{Control Theory}\label{ch:control_theory}

This chapter is concerned with control theory. 

\section{Control Schemes}\label{sec:control_schemes}

Control barrier functions with \texttt{mycite}:\mycite{ames.2019a}. 

Control barrier functions with \texttt{cite}:\cite{ames.2019a}


\printbibliography


\end{document}
```

The `reference.bib`:

```
@inproceedings{ames.2019a,
  title = {Control {{Barrier Functions}}: {{Theory}} and {{Applications}}},
  shorttitle = {Control {{Barrier Functions}}},
  booktitle = {2019 18th {{European Control Conference}} ({{ECC}})},
  author = {Ames, Aaron D. and Coogan, Samuel and Egerstedt, Magnus and Notomista, Gennaro and Sreenath, Koushil and Tabuada, Paulo},
  year = {2019},
  month = jun,
  pages = {3420--3431},
  doi = {10.23919/ECC.2019.8796030},
  abstract = {This paper provides an introduction and overview of recent work on control barrier functions and their use to verify and enforce safety properties in the context of (optimization based) safety-critical controllers. We survey the main technical results and discuss applications to several domains including robotic systems.},
}
```

The error is `Package biblatex Error: Incompatible package 'natbib'.`

Comment: The accepted answer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45934/35864 works fine for me. Can you share a complete example document that shows what you are trying to do, please? Please also tell us how you compile your document. A document using `biblatex` will need to be compiled with LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864).

Comment: I use `pdflatex` and that already fails to compile due to the `natbib` incompatibility.

Comment: OK, it seems like I mixed up the `tufte-common.def` files and the one I had in my directory didn't had the `nobib` option yet. Using `\renewcommand{\cite}[2][0pt]{\sidenote[][#1]{\fullcite{#2}}}` from https://github.com/christopheradams/tufte-latex/issues/60 restored the previous behaviour. Now I've to figure how to shorten the `fullcite` to only author + year.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you managed to get `biblatex` up and running with `tufte-book` (a relatively recent version of the class should define the `nobib` option), I will only focus on the question of getting author-year citations.

That is done by switching the style from `alphabetic` to `authoryear`. If you want your citations in the sidenotes, use `autocite=footnote,`. Use the command `\autocite` to cite any entries.

```
\documentclass[nobib]{tufte-book}

\usepackage[
  backend=bibtex8,
  style=authoryear,
  maxbibnames=99,
  giveninits=true,
  url=false,
  autocite=footnote,
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Control Theory}\label{ch:control_theory}

This chapter is concerned with control theory.

\section{Control Schemes}\label{sec:control_schemes}

Control barrier functions with \texttt{cite}: \autocite{sigfridsson}


\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Citation "Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998" in side note.]